# get list of unused ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have current table named **Article**:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | artikel_a |
| 2 | artikel_b |
| 3 | artikel_c |

`id` is a `numeric(5, 0)`

Its very important that similar articles have very similar IDs, so my client wants to see list of all the possible (currently unused) id numbers when he creates a new article record. That way they can look at a range that fits for current article creation.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: So up to 99,999 open slots.   Seems like a big picklist.

Comment: It's poor practice in a relational database to manipulate ID values like this. **Let the database manage them!** If you _really_ need to show a field with a related ID, you typically want to use a _separate column_.

Comment: its not auto generated atm, we are making an transition from as400 filled with ids that were never auto generated
and now when the as400 is gone we ant to go to auto generated, but we can't atm

the company exist for 35 years now and we have a really fun database atm that we cannot change to much in filled with mess from 30 years ago and wrong decisions, and a new system + db that needs to comunicate with that sytem correctly

Comment: Feels like a Gap-and-Islands of available IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] int,[name] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'aaa')
,(2,'bbb')
,(3,'ccc')
,(25,'ddd')
,(50,'eee')


Select R1 = min(N)
      ,R2 = max(N)
 From  (
        Select N
              ,Grp = N-row_number() over (order by N)
         From  (
                Select Top 99999 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
               ) src
         where not exists (Select 1 from  @YourTable where N=id)
       ) A
 Group By Grp
```

**Results of Available IDs**

```
R1  R2
4   24
26  49
51  99999
```

**Note:**

`Subquery A` will give you a long list of open ID's

Comment: Thanks again! And if i update the top select to:. Select R1 = min(N)
      ,R2 = max(N), r3= count(n) it wil give me the amount of numbers that section has right?

Comment: @LaurensWolf correct.   Well done!

Comment: is there an easy way to let the row numbers in this query start form 10000?

Comment: @LaurensWolf Sure.   N=9999+Row_Number()  ...